# how to read xml file on the svn server with php...?

Tags: php

I'm working on a project in my work, before a week a found a problem which i could not solve it till now!!

my project: i create a web side in php for the company where i work to display some Statistics
and the informations for these Statistics i should read it from a xml file on the repository svn.
i had get a privateKey and a https pasword  for the log in to do that...
but the problem that i don't know how to get the https access to svn with the php script cuse i had not did it bevore... i also don't know if it possible??

so if you think you could help with your comments it would be grateful...

thank in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a web server such as Apache configured with mod_dav, you can access the files on your SVN repository like you would with any resource on the web and parse the XML.

[How To Configure Web Access To Subversion Repositories Using Apache](http://www.howtoforge.com/subversion_web_access_apache)

Comment: hey Jahufar,  thanks for the quick reply but i use always the  xampp for all my developments where there is also Apache in, so the should be no other problems  here ??

Comment: and also because of the  https access?? how should i put the privateKey in the php request by the log in  while doing the handshake ??